# Arithmetic overflow error message in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my stored procedure I'm inserting some data into a temporary table and then selecting them. But for several hours I can't resolve the following problem. I tried many solutions, but I keep getting the following error:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.

Here is my SQL Server 2008 stored procedure:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[spr_Remuneration_Report2]
   @Action int = 1,
   @AgentID int = null,
   @ProviderID int = null,
   @date1 datetime = null,
   @date2 datetime = null
as
   if @Action = 1
   begin
      declare @tblAgents as table(AgentID int, ProviderID int, 
                                  TurnOver decimal(8, 2) null, 
                                  ProviderSum decimal(8, 2) null)

      declare @tmp as table(AgentID int)

      insert into @tmp
         select AgentID 
         from Agents 
         where parentID = @AgentID and agentType = 0

      while exists(select top(1) * from @tmp)
      begin
         declare @tmpAgentID as int

         select top(1) @tmpAgentID = agentid  
         from @tmp

         insert into @tblAgents
            select @tmpAgentID, @ProviderID, SUM(pr.PaySum), SUM(pr.ProviderSum)
            from Payment_Report pr
            inner join Agents a on pr.AgentID = a.AgentID
            where a.hrccrt like '%.' + CAST(@tmpAgentID as nvarchar(10)) + '.%' 
              and pr.ProviderID = @ProviderID
              and pr.Status = 2 
              and (pr.RegDateTime between @date1 and DATEADD(s, -1, @date2))
                --
         delete from @tmp where AgentID = @tmpAgentID
      end

      select 
          tb.AgentID, (a.name + ' ' + a.surname) as AgentName, tb.ProviderID,
          p.Name as Provider, tb.TurnOver, tb.ProviderSum,
          SUM(cast(tb.ProviderSum * ap.Remuneration / 100 as decimal(5, 2))) as Remuneration
      from 
          @tblAgents tb
      inner join 
          Agents a on tb.AgentID = a.AgentID
      inner join 
          Agent_Provider ap on tb.ProviderID = ap.ProviderID and tb.AgentID = ap.AgentID
      inner join 
          Provider p on tb.ProviderID = p.ID
      where 
          ap.Enabled = 'True' and tb.TurnOver is not null
      group by 
          tb.AgentID, a.name+ ' ' + a.surname, tb.ProviderID, p.Name, 
          tb.TurnOver, tb.ProviderSum
    end
```

Comment: You are trying to insert a value that is too big to fit in one of the numeric columns.  Be aware that `decimal(8, 2)` can hold a _total_ of 8 digits, not 8 digits before the decimal and 2 after.

Comment: Also there is "as decimal(5, 2)" which can be not enough

Comment: just try to work with decimal(5,2) decimal(8, 2)  decimal(11, 2) or decimal(10, 2) and Replace INT to BIGINT

Comment: If you were able to get an answer, please post it as an answer and accept it. This will help anyone else with the same issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue is solved by replacing `decimal(5, 2)` to `decimal(11, 2)` in `select` statement.
The rest of the code seems correct in my case.